# How to log values which raised KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-apply

Given this DataFrame, `df`:

```
     Player 1    Player 2
0    Thiem D.  Almagro N.
1  Almagro N.   Ferrer D.
2    Nadal R.    Thiem D.
```

and mapping `d`:

```
d = {
    'Thiem D.': 'Dominic Thiem',
    'Nadal R.': 'Rafael Nadal',
    'Ferrer D.': 'David Ferrer',
}
```

I want to rename player names and while doing so I want to keep track of elements not existing in the mapping (save to a file, or just print).

The first part of the assingment I can achieve with this line:

```
player_columns = ['Player 1', 'Player 2']
df[player_columns] = df[player_columns].applymap(lambda x: d.get(x, x))
```

Which results in:

```
        Player 1       Player 2
0  Dominic Thiem     Almagro N.
1     Almagro N.   David Ferrer
2   Rafael Nadal  Dominic Thiem
```

`Almagro N.` is not existing entry in the mapping hence why it could not be renamed. And I would like to capture this name.

I am aware I can subclass `UserDict` object and implement this behavoir there but I am curious if there is other way about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and get all [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `boolean mask` by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
df1 = df[player_columns].stack()
print (df1)
0  Player 1      Thiem D.
   Player 2    Almagro N.
1  Player 1    Almagro N.
   Player 2     Ferrer D.
2  Player 1      Nadal R.
   Player 2      Thiem D.
dtype: object

print (df1[df1.map(d).isnull()].unique())
['Almagro N.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to split up your operation into multiple operations.

First you can do the mapping

```
df.applymap(d.get)

        Player 1       Player 2
0  Dominic Thiem           None
1           None   David Ferrer
2   Rafael Nadal  Dominic Thiem
```

This gives you the players that cannot be mapped as `None`

Now you can check for the `None`s

```
df[df.applymap(d.get).isnull()]

     Player 1    Player 2
0         NaN  Almagro N.
1  Almagro N.         NaN
2         NaN         NaN
```

If you want these as a list of names that count not be mapped, you can simply do

```
unmappables = df[df.applymap(d.get).isnull()]
player1s = unmappables['Player 1'].values.tolist()
player2s = unmappables['Player 2'].values.tolist()
pd.Series((player1s + player2s)).dropna().unique()
```

Gives

```
array(['Almagro N.'], dtype=object)
```